# input type range with hammerjs swipe detection not useable on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, html, hammer.js, swipe-gesture

I am developing a web app with a small menu on the right side which i want to swipe in and out.

So i included hammerjs added a swipe to the document body and swipe out te side menu on left swipe and back in on right swipe. Works like a charm.

Now my problem i have also slider () on the page if i add the hammerjs swipe detection i can´t move the slider anymore. On firefox the slider gets slow and hangs sometimes.

When i remove the hammerjs detection the slider works as expected. Does anyone hav a a clue how I could solve the problem ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="slide" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100">
</div>
<div id="text">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(document.getElementById('container'));
mc.add(new Hammer.Swipe({
    direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL
}));

var textElement = document.getElementById('text');
textElement.innerHTML= 'noSwipe';
mc.on('swipe', function (e) {
    textElement.innerHTML = 'swipe'+e.direction;     
});
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

I´ve made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv856y1x/5/) which shows the problem.

Comment: Try always to show important parts regarding to your code, even when you include a JS fiddle (this can be deleted and we'll loss reference to the problem).

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue, only that helped me is preventing Bubbling of touch events.

```
var stop = function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
};
$element.on('touchmove', stop);
$element.on('touchstart',stop);
$element.on('touchend', stop);
```

Actually it's enought to prevent 'touchmove', but I added 'start' and 'end' for reliability.